unable to login via putty ssh to my ec2 linux instance in aws : no supported authentication methods available
i am new in aws,
i created two linux instances : amazon linux and ubuntu linux
I downloaded RSA ppk key pairs + imported to putty, however I am unable to login via putty,
i get this error
no supported authentication methods available;

when I logged via web console to amazon  linux, i wass surpised that there is no auth.log

so I checked on ubuntu and I found this logs:


Apr  3 06:19:36 ip sshd[11329]: userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
Apr  3 06:19:38 ip sshd[11329]: Connection closed by authenticating user ubuntu port 4798 [preauth]

Any idea

Ensure that the permissions on your private key file (.ppk) are set correctly. It should not be publicly viewable for SSH to accept it. You can set permissions using chmod:
chmod 400 your_key.pem
